Second time derivatives of rotation matrices
We know that the time derivative of a rotaiton matrix $\dot{R} = R\omega^{\times}$, where $(.)^\times:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathfrak{so}(3)$ denotes the hat map, and $\omega$ is the angular velocity.
Are there any closed form expression for the second time derivate of rotation matrix, i.e., what is $\ddot{R}$? So far, my calculation goes as follows:
$\begin{aligned} \ddot{R} &= \frac{d}{dt}(R\omega^{\times}) \\ \implies \ddot{R} &= \dot{R}\omega^{\times} + R\dot{\omega}^{\times} \\ \implies \ddot{R} &= R\left(\omega^{\times}\omega^{\times} + \dot{\omega}^{\times}\right)\end{aligned}$
But is this correct? I think I am missing other terms regarding cross-products, but not sure. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Can you define a rotation matrix? As far as I am concerned, a rotation matrix which isn't a function of time has zero time derivative.

Your approach is rock solid.
